# jQuery - Populating pagination element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm populating `ul.pagination` links based on row returns. There is a slight problem however. I currently have over `12` rows returned, and the `pagination()` function is only displaying one button. How can I get `buttons` to equal `2` if `count` is `14` rows ?

```
//populate pagination
function pagination(data) {
    var options = $("ul.pagination");
    var count = Object.keys(data).length;
    var buttons = (count / 12);
    //alert(buttons);
    for (var i = 1; i <= buttons; i++) {
        options.append($("<li />").html('<a class="page" id="' + i + '" href="#">' + i + '</a>'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Math.ceil((count / 12))` to get the number of buttons

```
function pagination(data) {
    var options = $("ul.pagination");
    var count = Object.keys(data).length;
    var buttons = Math.ceil((count / 12));
    //alert(buttons);
    for (var i = 1; i <= buttons; i++) {
        options.append($("<li />").html('<a class="page" id="' + i + '" href="#">' + i + '</a>'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice ... I actually tried ceil before ... but I was counting the rows that were limited to 12 :) ... little mistakes are great!

Comment: append can minfy like this also.`options.append("<li /><a class='page' id='" + i + "' href='#'>" + i + "</a>");`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Math.ceil()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```js
var initialFloat = parseFloat(14 / 12);
var roundedUp = Math.ceil(initialFloat);
console.log(roundedUp);
```